# Is there any way to re-define an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following array in my program:

```
int foo[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
//Do something with foo, but then there's no use with it afterwards
```

Since I need a lot more "single-use" arrays just like this, I want to re-define it like the following:

```
foo[] = {5,2,3}; //Raises an error
```

Note the array size could vary.

The only solution I've got is to create a new array for each re-definition, but that would be too much storage.

Is there any way of re-defining? Or is there any other solutions?

Comment: "but that would be too much storage." - Are you *sure*? If a variable is no longer used, the compiler may well reuse its storage. And if you have multiple of these in one function, maybe you should just split the function? Once a function ends, its stack space is sure to be reclaimed.

Comment: It seems what you really want is a [*vector*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: ***Is there any way of re-defining?*** Not an array which is fixed size at compile time.

Comment: Short answer: no.    Partial explanation:  An array can be initialised where it is defined, but cannot be redefined (i.e.  a second array of the same name defined in the same scope) or reassigned.    It is possible to define a pointer that initially points at the first element of an array, and subsequently reassign that pointer to point at the first element of another array (assuming the two arrays have elements of the same type and distinct names, and the pointer is to that same type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the array must be able to vary its size, you could consider using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of raw arrays and reassigning the vector whenever you need a new "array":

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
   std::vector<int> foo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   assert(foo.size() == 5);

   foo = {5, 2, 3}; // <-- reassign
   assert(foo.size() == 3);

}
```

The assignment replaces the vector's contents with those of the initializer list. No additional memory allocation will occur if the vector has enough capacity to store it.

Comment: using run time dynamic types with all the overhead seems not a solution for OPs question in my eyes.

Comment: @Klaus the array must be able to vary its size.

Comment: No, there are two arrays with fixed size with the same name at different places in the code. It might be one possible solution to have a single array which persists and change it size which means it is not longer an array but some container. But this is quite a different approach! And adding this overhead seems not acceptable if adding simply 4 braces to the code will do the same without any overhead. See answer from DeducibleSteak. Only my opinion!

Comment: The question suggests storage is the issue, not cpu overhead.

Comment: Note that both the arrays {1,2,3,4,5} and {5,2,3} will have to be stored *somewhere* in the program. Probably not on the stack, but somewhere. That's how the data gets into the vector in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Well, an array is not a first class object, but looks more like the beginning of a memory zone that will contain a sequence of objects. Because of that, the C++ does not allow to directly assign to an array. Full stop (BTW the ancestor C language does not either).

Workarounds:

- use a pointer to a dynamic array. Simple but it will require you to initialize the content of each new array. And you are supposed to take care of freeing the array before reusing the pointer - not really the C++ philosophy...
- use a vector. Exactly the previous way but nicely encapsulated in the vector class that will take care of allocation management and current size for you
- use one single array of the size of the longuest arrays you want to uses and copy the expected data there

In those ways (except for the vector which is much more programmer friendly, you are supposed to keep track of the current used length

But if the reason is to save memory, the simplest and most efficient way is to directly use a pointer to initialized arrays. If you can extract the initialization data at run time, it must be present somewhere since build time, so why not directly use that memory(*)? The only downside I can imagine is that you will have track the length of the pointed array.

---

There is one notable exception. In some embedded system, initialization data can be stored in read only memory. In that case, you cannot directly use that memory if you need to write in it...

Answer (score 3):

You can always just open & close a new scope for the lifetime of such "temporary" variables:

```
void bar() {
    {
        int foo[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        // Do something with the first foo
    }
    {
        int foo[] = {5, 2, 3};
        // Do something with the second foo
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if `foo` is a **data member**, though.

Comment: @眠りネロク   Nothing will work if `foo` is a data member, short of destroying the containing object and constructing another object of the same type.   Arrays cannot be reassigned in the manner you seek.